# Change plain text color by indentation in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am interested in giving lectures and taking notes in simple text files within VSCode (since I already use it for coding).

However, for the life of me I cannot figure out how to change simple text color.  What I want is to have one text color at one indentation depth.  For instance,

```
Notes:
    a:
    b:
```

`Notes` would be a different color than `a` and `b`.  I want this for clarity of bullet points.  Is there a simple way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can color lines with different indentation differently with an extension like [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight).  For instance I can get this:

[image: demo of Highlight extension]

with this code in settings.json:

```
"highlight.regexes": {

  "((?<!.))(\\w.*)": [
    {},
    {
      "color": "green",
      "fontWeight": "bold",
      // "outline": "1px solid #fff",
      "letterSpacing": "1px"
    }
  ],
  "((?<!.))(  )(\\w.*)": [
    {},
    {},
    {
      "color": "yellow",
    }
  ],
  "((?<!.))(    )(\\w.*)": [
    {},
    {},
    {
      "color": "red",
    }
  ]
}
```

My setup inserts 2 spaces per tab - I found that you need to use spaces in your regex, not something handier like `(\\t\\t)` or `( ){4}` but instead must use `(    )` - that is 4 spaces representing two tabs for me - for the regex to work in the extension.

For more styling options, see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationRenderOptions

The extension link shows how to restrict this to whichever filetype(s) you wish.  Which I incorporated into the second batch of code below.

If you want only the bullet headings, like `a-z` or `1-9` to be colored and not the rest of the text on that line, that can be achieved in the regex too:

```
"highlight.regexes": {

  "((?<!.))(\\w.*)": { 
    "regexFlags": "gi", 
    // "filterLanguageRegex": "markdown", 
    "filterFileRegex": "Notes.*\\.txt", 
    "decorations": [
      {}, 
      { 
        "color": "green",
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "letterSpacing": "1px",
        "textDecoration": "underline"
      },
    ]
  },


  "((?<!.))(  )([a-z1-9][:\\.])(.*)":  {
    "regexFlags": "gi", 
    // "filterLanguageRegex": "markdown", 
    "filterFileRegex": "Notes.*\\.txt", 
    "decorations": [
      {},
      {},
      {
        "color": "yellow",
      },
      {}
    ]
  },


  "((?<!.))(    )([a-z1-9][:\\.])(.*)": {
    "regexFlags": "gi", 
    // "filterLanguageRegex": "markdown", 
    "filterFileRegex": "Notes.*\\.txt", 
    "decorations": [
      {},
      {},
      {
        "color": "red",
      },
      {}
    ]
  }
```

[Restricted to files of the form `Notes1.txt`, `Notes blsdfs .txt` and similar.]

[image: demo 2 of Highlight extension]

Obviously, you can have as many levels of indentation as you want with more regex entries following the same pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Syntax highlighting is not related to indentation, but rather tokens and scopes.

From [Syntax Highlight Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#textmate-grammars):

> VS Code uses TextMate grammars to break text into a list of tokens.
> TextMate grammars are a structured collection of Oniguruma regular
> expressions and are typically written as a plist or JSON. You can find
> a good introduction to TextMate grammars [here](https://www.apeth.com/nonblog/stories/textmatebundle.html), and you can take a look
> at existing TextMate grammars to learn more about how they work

Many folks take notes in Markdown, which offers syntax highlighting and formatting. Maybe give that a try?